# How to pass variable from helperclass to finish method in batchclass

Tags: apex, batch, null, global-variables

I have a bachclass with a scope of some records. These records have a startdate and enddate field. With a helperclass I set the earliest startdate and the lates enddate of these records in 2 variables.

How do I get these varables into my finish method of my bach class. Currenly they return null.

Batchclass:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<JMG_Target__c> scope){
    if(scope.size() > 0){
        for(JMG_Target__c target : scope){
            targetsMap.put(target.JMG_User__c,target);
            TaskHelper.setLowestHighestTargetDates(target);   
        }
    } 
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
{
    Datetime lowestStartDate = TaskHelper.lowestStartDate;
    Datetime highestEndDate = TaskHelper.highestEndDate;
    System.debug('lowestStartDatefinish: ' + lowestStartDate); 
    System.debug('highestEndDatefinish: ' + highestEndDate);
}
```

Helperclass:

```
public class TaskHelper {
    Public static Datetime lowestStartDate;
    Public static Datetime highestEndDate;
    
    public static void setLowestHighestTargetDates(JMG_Target__c targ){ 
        if(lowestStartDate == null || lowestStartDate > targ.JMG_Target_Start_Date__c) lowestStartDate = targ.JMG_Target_Start_Date__c;
        if(highestEndDate == null || highestEndDate < targ.JMG_Target_End_Date__c) highestEndDate = targ.JMG_Target_End_Date__c;
        System.debug('lowestStartDateTaskHelper: ' + lowestStartDate); 
        System.debug('highestEndDateTaskHelper: ' + highestEndDate); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we can't call the finish method from our code and it gets called from SFDC end after all the batches are processed, **you can't pass a member variable of the helper class to the finish method**.

In your case, if you want to set "lowestStartDate" & "highestEndDate", you can do the following :

1. Implement the Database.Stateful interface
2. Create "lowestStartDate" & "highestEndDate" as member variables in your class (non static)
3. Return the values from the helper and set these member variables in your execute method.
4. These member variables can be accessed in the finish method

- static member variables don’t retain their values and are reset between each transactions

Reference : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm (look for Using State in Batch Apex section)

Comment: Thanks that works!